# Need to find determine current step in workflow

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have workflow set up for invoice review. I need to create a report that filters the data to show the current workflow step (lowest approval sequence for each invoice where ApprovedYN is N.) The issue I'm running into is how the logic for OptionalReview is applied.

**Scenario 1:**

```
|Invoice|Line|ApprovalSeq|Reviewer|ApprovedYN|OptionalReviewer|
|-------|----|-----------|--------|----------|----------------|
|123    |1   |1          |Amy     |N         |N               |
|123    |1   |1          |Jim     |N         |N               |
|123    |1   |1          |John    |Y         |N               |
|123    |1   |2          |Mark    |N         |N               |
```

If OptionalReviewer = N for all rows, then only the rows with the lowest Line/ApprovalSeq where Approved YN = N would be returned in the query results. Expected results:

```
|Invoice|Line|ApprovalSeq|Reviewer|ApprovedYN|OptionalReviewer|
|-------|----|-----------|--------|----------|----------------|
|123    |1   |1          |Amy     |N         |N               |
|123    |1   |1          |Jim     |N         |N               |
```

**Scenario 2:**

```
|Invoice|Line|ApprovalSeq|Reviewer|ApprovedYN|OptionalReviewer|
|-------|----|-----------|--------|----------|----------------|
|456    |1   |1          |Amy     |N         |Y               |
|456    |1   |1          |John    |Y         |Y               |
|456    |1   |2          |Mark    |N         |N               |
```

If OptionalReviewer = Y for all rows of an invoice/line/approvalseq and atleast one row has ApprovedYN = Y, then that invoice/line/qpproval seq is fully approved and would not be the current workflow step; this line(s) would not be returned in the query results. The current workflow setp would be the next line and/or approval sequence. Expected results:

```
|Invoice|Line|ApprovalSeq|Reviewer|ApprovedYN|OptionalReviewer|
|-------|----|-----------|--------|----------|----------------|
|456    |1   |2          |Mark    |N         |N               |
```

**Scenario 3:**

```
|Invoice|Line|ApprovalSeq|Reviewer|ApprovedYN|OptionalReviewer|
|-------|----|-----------|--------|----------|----------------|
|789    |1   |1          |Amy     |Y         |N               |
|789    |1   |1          |John    |N         |Y               |
|789    |1   |2          |Mark    |N         |N               |
|789    |1   |2          |Jim     |N         |Y               |
```

If an invoice line has some ApprovalSeq lines with optional reviewer Y, then those lines are ignored (approval not required). If all other reviewers in the ApprovalSeq have approved, then the line is fully approved, and I would need the next Line/ApprovalSeq combination to be returned. Expected results:

```
|Invoice|Line|ApprovalSeq|Reviewer|ApprovedYN|OptionalReviewer|
|-------|----|-----------|--------|----------|----------------|
|789    |1   |2          |Mark    |N         |N               |
```

Comment: I find your logic really hard to follow.  And it isn't complete because it doesn't cover the optional reviewer has no Ys case.

Comment: Your written logic does not match the results you are showing. For example, `123/ 1 / 2`  and `456 / 1 / 2` have no rows within their 'group' with OptionalReviewer = 'Y' but your written logic says these should not be in your results. Can you edit you question, review your logic and if still not clear, explain the logic for every line in the results.

Comment: I  made some edits to how I set my question up. Please see if this helps to clarify the logic. If not, I can provide additional details.